# What is the genomic position of HLA-B*1502 variation?

Tags: genomics, hla

I've searched the position and SNP ID of **HLA-B*1502** variation. However, I couldn't find that where this variant exactly located on genome or HLA-B gene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HLA-B*1502 is not a SNP ID but rather, a name of [an allele of HLA-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLA-B75). This allele is made up of multiple mutations which can be found [here](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/get_allele.cgi?B*1502).